# Embedding PowerBI Dash Board/Report into Web application

Tags: c#, powerbi

I am trying to embed power BI  Dash Board report into Web application.

1) I have configured the application using this Microsoft link and their sample application from github  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-your-organization.

2) I have also tried configuring using this  documentation https://bitbucket.org/omnistream/powerbi-api-example\

I am accessing  the end point with my company email id /password . below is the details. i have admin rights on dash board report and I have power BI pro user account.

Post End point: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token

Request Header : 
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: login.windows.net
content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: xxx

with request body : 
grant_type=password&scope=openid&username=myUserName@mycompany.com&password=MyPassword&client_id=XXXXX&resource=https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api&client_secret=XXXXX

it throws below error: 
error_description=AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50126: Invalid username or password
Trace ID: c13c59dc-79e2-4169-bae2-06c402310100
Correlation ID: a747a226-362a-45aa-956a-122629fa9863
Timestamp: 2018-08-06 21:27:59Z

Do i need to configure or create Master Power BI account separately ?

or if my company network interfering with Post request to mask the user id/password, is there any tool which can help me to trace this network issue?

Comment: Did you include your domain in `MyUserName` (i.e. MyUserName@example.com). Did you URI escape your username/password?

Comment: its with domain name. updating the post to avoid confusion.

Comment: Everything looks fine to me in terms of the request you are sending (the only difference from my working configuration is that you are missing a `/` at the end of the POST endpoint). It is possible that you have not authorised the app (client_id) to access your user's (myUserName@mycompany.com) data. You can do this either through the azure admin portal, or by using one of the interactive authentication flows (which will pop up a checkbox asking for permission).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even after Bypassing the company proxy for credentials it was not working. 
finally, I logged the ticket with Microsoft  and able make it work for only one of the option i.e. Native application. Below is the step

1) Download 'App owns data ' application from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples). And Register your power Bi application in Azure Portal as "Native application" for Application Type.  Visit the link #1 in question for details about configuring PowerBI  application web page embedding.

2) Open project and import all required Dll using NUget package manager.

3) configure cloud.config with these values in project.

```
  <appSettings>
  <add key="authorityUrl" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize/" />
  <add key="resourceUrl" value="https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api" />   
  <add key="apiUrl" value="https://api.powerbi.com/" />
  <add key="embedUrlBase" value="https://app.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/" /> 
</appSettings>
```

4) Configure your web.config file with these values in project.

```
    <appSettings file="Cloud.config">
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />    
    <add key="applicationId" value="xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx" /> <!--For PowerBI Native application ID-->    
    <add key="workspaceId" value="xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx" />
    <!-- The id of the report to embed. If empty, will use the first report in group -->     
    <add key="reportId" value="xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx" />
    <!-- Note: Do NOT leave your credentials on code. Save them in secure place. -->
    <add key="pbiUsername" value="XXXXXXXXX@yourcompany.com" />
    <add key="pbiPassword" value="xxxxxxxx" />    
  </appSettings>
```

5) Publish your report on power BI site , create dash board , fill the report id and work space id in above  web.config setting.

6) Execute the application. it should work for Embed report, dashboard and Tile types.